# How can I switch between using one class or another in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<i style="margin-right: 0.5em; color: #EEEEEE;" class="icon-home icon-4x"></i>
```

I would like to change the color of the SVG icon depending on if my ui-router state as follows:

- If the state includes 'admin' I would like it to use the class red-icon
- If the state does not include 'admin' I would like it to use the class blue-icon

I have done something like this before:

```
data-ng-class="{ current: $state.includes('admin') }"
```

But how can I make it switch between the two colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would be the simplest:

```
<i data-ng-class="{ 'red-icon': $state.includes('admin'), 'blue-icon': !$state.includes('admin') }"></i>
```

If it gets any more complicated than that then you might want to [return an object, array or string](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass) from a controller method:

```
<i data-ng-class="iconStyle()"></i>
```

Inside a controller:

```
$scope.iconStyle = function (){
    return { 
        'red-icon': $state.includes('admin'), 
        'blue-icon': !$state.includes('admin') 
    }
}
```

or

```
$scope.iconStyle = function (){
    if ($state.includes('admin')) {
        return 'red-icon';
    } else {
        return 'blue-icon';
    }
}
```